# Sitecore, Content Editor, not generating links

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am having problem with content editor, I am using tool bar of content editor to generate hyperlinks, following is my HTML

```
<li><a href="~/media/7c3ac3d7756842a6b8050cf0a3c92f65.ashx">w</a></li>
<li><a href="~/media/38d4f01b1a9b4624b43230d663b5f799.ashx">a</a></li>
<li><a href="~/media/e5025c794ca14a96a6966f11f34c9507.ashx">awealth</a></li>
<li><a href="~/media/3789155fba474b4d92d3e6489d857262.ashx">wwealth</a></li>
<li><a href="~/media/38d4f01b1a9b4624b43230d663b5f799.ashx">ds</a></li>
```

some items are successfully linked to appropriate files but some links are rendered as they are and when i click on them i see page not found. IDs are valid, I have verified.

What could be the reason, Why some links aren't converted to links to  actual files? Any other way to use content editor?

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the field using Sitecore Controls:

```
<sc:Text runat="server" field="MyFieldName" />
```

sc:Text derives from the FieldRenderer.
You should consider reading http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/presentation_component_api_cookbook_sc64-a4.pdf (sc:Text is used on page 36)